# iOS app crashes when Podfile has 'use_frameworks!' option

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, crash, cocoapods

I have a Single View app setup with CocoaPods that includes only two pods, 'MBProgressHUB' and 'ImojiSDK'.

When CocoaPods is setup as a static library, the project builds and runs normally. When I configure CocoaPods to use frameworks, by including the 'use_frameworks!' flag in the Podfile, the project builds, but crashes when run.

Question is, why does it run fine as a static library, but not when using frameworks?

The crash happens when I try to create a new ImojiSDK session in the view's viewDidLoad:

```
IMImojiSession *session = [IMImojiSession imojiSession]; //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
session.contentCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];
session.contentCache.countLimit = 100;
```

Below are the Podfile and crash output from Xcode:

## PODFILE:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'

use_frameworks!

pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'ImojiSDK'
```

## CRASH OUTPUT:

```
2015-07-20 14:05:18.031 imoji[19887:323843] +[BFTask im_concurrentBackgroundTaskWithBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1041b6878
2015-07-20 14:05:18.035 imoji[19887:323843] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[BFTask im_concurrentBackgroundTaskWithBlock:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1041b6878'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104aafc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104746bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104ab6fad +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104a0d13c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104a0ccd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   imoji                               0x0000000104003962 -[IMMutableImojiSessionStoragePolicy performCleanupOnOldImages] + 93
    6   imoji                               0x0000000104002c4f -[IMMutableImojiSessionStoragePolicy initWithCachePath:persistentPath:] + 175
    7   imoji                               0x000000010400ec6d +[IMImojiSessionStoragePolicy temporaryDiskStoragePolicy] + 210
    8   imoji                               0x0000000104003dfc -[IMImojiSession init] + 76
    9   imoji                               0x000000010400e8c7 +[IMImojiSession imojiSession] + 41
    10  imoji                               0x0000000103fd6b8c -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 76
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010526d1d0 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010526d3ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000105188289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010518864f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105194de1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000105138417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010513b19e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010513a095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001085585e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049e341c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049d9165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049d8f25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001049d8366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000105139b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010513c8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    26  imoji                               0x0000000103fd6fef main + 111
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106579145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: do you use `Objective-C` or `Swift`  iOS7 or iOS8?

Comment: I am using Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

`use_frameworks!` enables Swift support by building your code in the new dynamic frameworks. Dynamic frameworks only support iOS 8

[CocoaPods 0.36 - Framework and Swift Support](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-0.36/)

Comment: The iOS deployment target is set to 8.4. Objective-C also supports frameworks.

Comment: @SpencerMüllerDiniz may I ask you why you need to use the pods as frameworks since it works as a static library

Comment: I have a keyboard extension in the project and ImojiSDK uses the Bolts library. The Bolts library uses API methods that are prohibited in extensions. The ImojiSDK developer suggests that, in this situation, the ImojiSDK pod should be used as a framework. See troubleshooting section here: https://cocoapods.org/?q=imojisdk

Comment: When using use_frameworks!, you should probably be using `@import`

Answer (score 0):

The ImojiSDK pod was recently updated for frameworks compatibility.
https://github.com/imojiengineering/imoji-ios-sdk

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I ended up not using the SDK and started using the REST API directly.